# How can I change visual studio 2008 solution resources to be linked and not embedded?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resources, persistence, resx

I'm developing a C# solution where I use files as external resources.
I need to this files to be modified without building all solution again.
I used to have shuch configuration and all went well.
I don't remember what I changed but now all resources are embedded in .exe file, I cannot find a way to make them linked again.

In resource properties in all resources `Persistence` option is diabled and is set to `Linked at compile time`, so I don't think this is the problem because I think it must be this way.

I think it could be a language configuration, problem started when I changed a form language propiertie that created an language specific resx but later it returned to its original configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take them out of resources, add (add existing file) them to the project, make sure you set the properties on each one to copy if newer, assuming you are happy to have them deployed in to the same folder as the exe/dll that depends on them.

Comment: I did it but this only makes the files to be copied, if I modify program still using the original version, even if I delete them program runs without any exception.

Comment: Huh? You've got to recompile, and change the code to load from discrete files not thr esources that are no longer in the exe/dlls. If you were trying to avoid that, you've got problems, you'd have to hack new compiled resources into the exe.

Comment: What I want is to modify resources without recompiling, I used to do that, but now I can't, I don't remember what I changed. If I change resources nothing happens, If I delete resources still working.

Comment: You can't modify resources without recompiling. They are compiled. You can have a file associated with your application and look it up at run time. If you can delete the resource and it works it didn't use it. If they are simple external files and not resources, clear out your build directory. e.g Clean Solution.

Comment: I could once, I don't know how but I could modify them without recompiling becase they were linked. I solved this whit files that look them up at run time. thanks